# How to repaint GUI after a certain element was removed?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

I'm making an app where a user would be able to add a button to the screen or remove it (I don't have those options implemented yet).  So, for now I'm manually populating it with a for() loop and manually removing one of the buttons.  My problem is that after the button has been removed (the removal action in the main()), there's just a blank spot.  I want to be able to repaint the screen after I remove one of those buttons.  In this example, index 2 (block #3) has been removed, leaving an empty space, where it was before... and I have no idea how to repaint it.  I've tried validating or repainting from different places in the program with no success.

Here's the code (**P.S.** I'm sure my code is not the most efficient way to accomplish what I'm trying to and I'm using setLayout(null), which is not a preferred method, but for now I'm just trying to learn certain things and then expand on that to better myself and my code):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

class TestApp extends JFrame{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Program");
    ArrayList<JButton> grid = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    private int w = 14;
    private static int amount = 102;
    private static int counter = 0;

    //Default Constructor (sets up JFrame)
    TestApp(){ 
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1186, 880));       
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        paintGrid();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void newWindow()
    {
        JFrame select_win = new JFrame("Selected Frame");
        JPanel select_panel = new JPanel();
        select_panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 800));
        select_panel.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        select_win.add(select_panel);
        select_win.pack();
        select_win.setResizable(false);
        select_win.setVisible(true);
        select_win.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void paintGrid()
    {   
        for(int i = 0, y = 4; i < ((amount / w) + (amount % w)); i++, y += 104)
        {
            for(int j = 0, x = 4; j < w && (counter < amount); j++, x += 84)
            {
                addBlock(counter, x, y);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }

    //Adds a block
    private void addBlock(int index, int x, int y){
        int height = 100;
        int width = 80;

        grid.add(new JButton("counter: " + (counter + 1)));
        (grid.get(index)).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        newWindow();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        (grid.get(index)).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        (grid.get(index)).setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        (grid.get(index)).setVisible(true);
        (grid.get(index)).setBounds(x, y, width, height);

        frame.add(grid.get(index));
    }  

    //Removes a block
    private void removeBlock(int index){
        frame.remove(grid.get(index));
        grid.remove(index);
        amount--;
        counter--;
    }  

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TestApp app = new TestApp();

                //testing block removal
                app.removeBlock(2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for details on layout managers

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yep, aiming for it... still scared, not sure why, lol

Comment: Layout managers a lot of information quickly and it can a little daunting to begin with, but start with the end in mind and don't be afraid to use multiple, compound layouts to achieve what it is you want

Comment: @MadProgrammer So, if I have let's say two JPanels stacked on top of each other in a JFrame, each one of those JPanels can have its own Layout?

Comment: Yes, anything that extends from `Container` (included `JPanel`) can have it's own layout manager...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, is not good to use `NullLayout`. To fix your problem you only need to do two changes:

Change the layout to `FlowLayout` on the constructor, like this:

```
 frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

Change the `setBounds` call to a `setPreferredSize`:

```
(grid.get(index)).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Now the `FlowLayout` will automatically align your items and you don't need to worry about it anymore.

Comment: Give the use of X/Y positioning, it might be better to use something like GridBagLayout, but baby steps might be called for.

Comment: It actually worked pretty darn well, and I like the layout better, it centers it nicely.  @MadProgrammer heh, yeah I was eyeballing GridBagLayout after you and a few other guys mentioned LayoutManager from my other question. :)

Answer (score 3):

The proper way would be: revalidate()

revalidate() method informs the layout manager that this component and all parents above it are marked as needing to be laid out. This means the Layout Manager will try to realign the components. Often used after removing components.

I would think that you will only know this if you are actually using Swing

Comment: Where would you place that in code?  It didn't work for me after I've tried it in main and in the removeBlock methods.  Luckily the FlowLayout does a nice job of correcting that for me... still curious why it's not doing it though without the layout manager's help.

Comment: Changed my code up a bit and I actually use your suggestion right now.  Thank you.